# How to log all web service client requests and responses

Tags: c#, logging, soap, web, toolkit

I have a very complicated and big project. There are so many web service calls inside project.  All service calls are logged in different tables on database. I need a central log mechanism to avoid all these different log tables.

I think there must be something like Soap Toolkit on client side to catch all service calls. How can I catch the calls and responses to log them to a desired database.?

Comment: Check it out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not a good idea to log to a database. There are several reasons for it, e.g. if, for some reason, there is an exception related to database, it will never get logged.

I would recommend using Log4net from Apache. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14819/How-to-use-log4net) is a good article on how to use log4net in asp.net project. It is a highly efficient and configurable method of logging.

Comment: Please refer to the example, it will show you how to use it with asp application as well as asp.net application

Comment: Actually i need an interface or api to catch requests more than logger. DB exceptions are not so important for me.